# Which one is correct about the usage of pthread_mutex_lock() function?

Tags: c, linux

I'm learning how to use global variables through multithreading, but I have a problem now: about `pthread_mutex_lock()` and `pthread_mutex_unlock()`.

Correct is usage in function1 or function2? If neither, how to use it correctly?

I just modified one of the elements in the array at that time. For example, after `thread1` changed `AllSensorInfoArray[2][66].sensorType`, the `thread1` will change `AllSensorInfoArray[2][67].sensorType`,now thread2 can change `AllSensorInfoArray[2][66].sensorType`. In other words, multiple threads are not allowed to modify `AllSensorInfoArray[2][66].sensorType` at the same time.

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t AllSensorMutex;

void *function1(void *arg)
{


    int t = 0, i = 0;
    /*
        some codes
    */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&AllSensorMutex);
    for (t = 0; t < 100; t++)
    {
        AllSensorInfoArray[i][t].sensorType = allData[2+t];
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&AllSensorMutex);
    /*
        some codes
    */
}

void *function2(void *arg)
{

    /*
        some codes
    */
    int t = 0, i = 0;
    for (t = 0; t < 100; t++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&AllSensorMutex);
        AllSensorInfoArray[i][t].sensorType = allData[2+t];
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&AllSensorMutex);
    }
    /*
        some codes
    */
}

int main(void)
{
    while(pthread_mutex_init(&AllSensorMutex, NULL))
    {
        printf("(%s) write mutex init error!\n", __FUNCTION__);
        sleep(1);
    }

    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    int ret = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, function1, NULL);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        printf("(%s) failed to create a pthread, return error code : %d.\n", __FUNCTION__, ret);
        exit(-1);
    }

    ret = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, function2, NULL);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        printf("(%s) failed to create a pthread, return error code : %d.\n", __FUNCTION__, ret);
        exit(-1);
    }
    while (1)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which one is correct depends on your desired behaviour. Which you have not described. If your application requires the whole array to be changed atomically wrt to each thread then the first one is correct. If your application requires sub-elements in the array be settable independenantly then the second one could be correct. So it's not really possible to answer based on the given info.

Comment: @ kaylum I see. Thank you very much for your answer. I have revised the question according to your request. I just want to modify the elements in the array at that time, so the way function2 works is right.

Comment: @ None Yes, thank you very much for your care. I have revised it.

Comment: "modified one of the elements in the array at that time." But that's not what your code does. It modifies many elements in the array (100 of them). So I don't think your edit makes it any clearer.

Comment: @ kaylum Thank you for your guidance. I now add another example. Can I make the problem description clearer?

Comment: @ kaylum In fact, I think I've got the answer, the answer you gave in the first place. Now I just take this opportunity to learn from you.

Comment: @ kaylum If I use the function 2 method, I use a and B functions frequently, which will make the program execution slow. is that so？

Answer (score 0):

> Correct is usage in function1 or function2?

Both are equally correct, and will work.  The first one is "better" for this particular case.

The first one, which takes the mutex for the duration of the loop is more *efficient*, because there is less overhead (of locking and unlocking the mutex).
It is best suited for things like copying data.

The second one, which takes the mutex for the duration of accessing each element, is better suited when the modification is more complicated and may take some time (relatively speaking), *and you only need to access that one element*. However, then you should only take the mutex for the modification itself, and not for the entire computation (or, say, sensor reading):

```
for (i = 0; i < sensor_count; i++) {
    value = read_sensor(i);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    sensor_reading[i] = value;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

instead of `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); sensor_reading[i] = read_sensor(i); pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);`, because this latter would just hold the mutex while reading the sensor, blocking other threads' access to the array for the duration of the `read_sensor(i)` call for no sensible reason.

Simple assignment or arithmetic on the array element is not 'slow', and therefore the first function is the recommended pattern here.

In general, the pattern

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    /* Do something */

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

only releases the mutex for a short duration, and depending on the pthreads implementation, it may not be long enough for any other thread to grab the mutex, even if they were already blocking/waiting on the mutex (in a pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) call).  It is not wrong or an error, though, it just works the same as

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {

    /* Do something */

}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

and is less efficient than this latter form, because the former does (`N`-1) extra pthread_mutex_lock() and pthread_mutex_unlock() calls, with no guarantees of any benefits of doing so.